# How can I return multiple rows as a single row in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

A few months ago our vendor added a capability to our ticketing system which lets us add any number of custom fields to a ticket.  I'd like to query these fields out along with the other call information for reporting purposes, but each extensible field is stored as a row in the database.  So basically you have something like this:

```
ext_doc_no    call_record    value
1             1001           Test
2             1001           test2
3             1001           moretest
```

What I'd like is to query back:

```
1001    Test    test2    moretest
```

I've tried to use PIVOT, but that's rather demanding about things like using an aggregate function.  Any other ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: I also tried querying each row separately into the main query, and using a function... but both methods are way too slow.  I need something to get all the rows at once, PIVOT them and then join into the main query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488020/what-is-your-most-useful-sql-trick-to-avoid-writing-more-code/488897#488897).

It does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: The really sad part is I've used this technique before... I blame the antibiotics. :P

Comment: This page is now 404'd

Answer (score 1):

See here  [Concatenate Values From Multiple Rows Into One Column Ordered](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Concatenate_Values_From_Multiple_Rows_Into_One_Column_Ordered) SQL 2005+

or for a 2000 version  [Concatenate Values From Multiple Rows Into One Column](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Concatenate_Values_From_Multiple_Rows_Into_One_Column)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a pivot (some systems call it a crosstab query).  That should help you google for additional help, but generally you need to know what columns you expect *before* writing the query.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/32004/

Using the script from above page.

```
    DECLARE @Values VARCHAR(1000)

    SELECT  @Values = COALESCE(@Values + ', ', '') + Value
    FROM .....
    WHERE ....

    SELECT @ValuesEND
```

EDIT: I don't want to be rude. But you could find this by searching "combining multiple rows into one".

Answer (score 0):

return data as XML

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
...JOIN....
FOR XML AUTO
```