# Multiple rows into single row with header name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

My problem is like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582840/how-can-i-return-multiple-rows-as-a-single-row-in-t-sql) but I am fetching data from different table:

```
Name   ID  Subject-name    obtained-marks
gumman  9   English              3
gumman  9   Islamic-Studies      4
gumman  9   Pak Studies          3
```

I want output like this:

```
ID   Name   English   Islamic-Studies   Pak-studies
9   gumman   3             4                3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select s.ID, s.Name, 
       MAX(case WHEN s.SubjectName = 'English'         THEN s.ObtainedMarks end) as 'English',
       MAX(case WHEN s.SubjectName = 'Islamic-Studies' THEN s.ObtainedMarks end) as 'Islamic-Studies',
       MAX(case WHEN s.SubjectName = 'Pak Studies'     THEN s.ObtainedMarks end) as 'Pak-studies'
From Students s
GROUP BY s.ID, s.Name
```

[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67020)

Comment: thank you for your help, I see demo, but a little problem is there. imagine subject names are unknown, so how can do like that in demo

Comment: @user1337945, If the list of subjects are unknows therfore the columns' headers are unknown, in theis case you should pivot the table data dynamically, and this is a common problem in sql server. Fortunately there are alot of workarounds for this. Just google for *SQL server PIVOT Table with dynamic columns* and you will find alot of useful threads like this: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx , and this: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx

Comment: thank you for helping me to manage my post. I solved my problem. first i fetch the related subjects from database and then comparing the the subject name in a loop using this statement ` MAX(case WHEN s.SubjectName = 'English'         THEN s.ObtainedMarks end) as 'English',` and Concatenating into query. finally I found my result.

Answer (score 4):

```
select ID,
       Name,
       [English],
       [Islamic-Studies],
       [Pak Studies]
from YourTable 
pivot
  (
    min([obtained-marks]) for [Subject-name] in ([English],
                                                 [Islamic-Studies],
                                                 [Pak Studies])
  ) as P
```